# parseInt returns undefined

Tags: facebook, undefined, fbjs, parseint

Facebook's code changes on Tuesday night have impacted how `parseInt` works in FBJS. Where I previously used it to convert decimal numbers to straight integers, now it always returns undefined.

For example:

```
return parseInt(decimalnum);
```

no longer works. Anyone figured out how we are supposed to round to integers now? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report. It's fixed on trunk now; it should be out tomorrow unless there's another push later today.

Comment: Alf, are you indicating you are a developer on Facebook responsible for the FBJS layer?

Comment: The fix is out; if you see any other FBJS breakage, please let me know.

@artlung: Yes, I broke this :(

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that `decimalnum` is not defined in your function. Try replacing your return with `return decimalnum;` -- you may still be returning undefined.

`parseInt` is not for rounding - it actually takes the integer component of a number, or coerces a string to be a number. If you want to round, use `Math.round`. Depending on your usage, you may find `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` useful.

1. [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
2. [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)
3. [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)
4. [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `parseInt(decimalnum, 10);` ?